# Grad School application that's submitted early with a decent LOR vs Application that's submitted rather late but with a better LOR

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, united-kingdom, physics

I am a final year bachelor's student in physics and I am applying to masters programs in physics, in the UK.

The places I am applying to have a rolling admissions process and I wanted to submit my applications by mid Feb latest, but still haven't done so. 
At this point, one of the professors I had asked for an LOR (a few months ago), says he is still not ready with his letter. Owing to time constraints I requested another professor who is now ready with his letter. Any letter in the application portals needs to be uploaded as a PDF so I will have access to it, before I hit submit. I have reason to believe that the first professor might write a better letter, since he has mentioned (to me and generally) how he normally approaches an LOR and he seems quite specific about where I'm applying to and the like. However, it seems like he may take atleast another week to complete his letter.

I wish to apply for a few external scholarships which have a late March deadline, but I can only apply for them if I have an acceptance from some university.

The letter that I currently have, seems rather basic and the same professor has given another student from my class an LOR for almost identical applications.

*Do I wait, and hope that the first professor gives me an answer (and a letter hopefully) or do I submit the application now as it is?*

Comment: Apply now or wait until next year...

Comment: Did you explain to the first professor that you need the letter to be able to submit the application? Did you give him a concrete deadline when you wanted it by? If he doesn't know when you need it, it's not likely to find its way to the top of his todo list.